# How does make find out of project dependices?

Tags: linux, gnu-make

After attempting to build git from source I encountered the following error when running the make command from the project root directory:

```
44stonelions@pop-os:~/dev/git$ make
    CC oss-fuzz/fuzz-commit-graph.o
In file included from ./commit-graph.h:4,
                 from oss-fuzz/fuzz-commit-graph.c:1:
./git-compat-util.h:380:10: fatal error: openssl/ssl.h: No such file or directory
  380 | #include <openssl/ssl.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Makefile:2720: oss-fuzz/fuzz-commit-graph.o] Error 1
```

After cloning openssl and running make install for the openssl project, the `ssl.h` header now exists in `/usr/local/include/openssl`. Now when I run make in the git root directory, it can find the `ssl.h` file, although I didn't have to provide any information about where this file was. My questions are:

- where does make search for included header files on linux by default? And,
- is there any way to check or configure which directories it is searching in?

I am quite new to Linux and don't really know my way around the file system, it would be nice to know where to look to see if I have things installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not `make` searching for the headers, it's the `gcc`. By default it searches for headers also in `/usr/local/include`. You can check your list of directories searched by asking the compiler to tell you so, like this:

```
$ gcc -v -E - < /dev/null
Using built-in specs.
...
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.
...
```

The command line above tells the compiler to be verbose and stop after preprocessing, while feeding it with empty input from `stdin`. This trick allows to get the compiler defaults, although it is specific to GCC.